# TypeError: PromiseReject called on non-object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`getFileReadStreamFromS3` throws an error.  When calling fn, I get a `TypeError: PromiseReject called on non-object` error message.  If I replace the last line with `.catch((e) => Promise.reject(e))`, then that error goes away and the error from `getFileReadStreamFromS3` is passed through.  Why can't I use the point-free style with just `Promise.reject`?  I know in this case I really don't need the catch at all if I was just passing through the error.

```
 const fn = () => Promise.resolve(id)
    .then(getMediaAssetMimeById(meta))
    .then(getFileReadStreamFromS3)
    .catch(Promise.reject);
```

Comment: It's a binding problem, `Promise.reject.bind(Promise)` works.

Comment: Apparently `Promise.reject()` refers to `this` inside its implementation and thus needs to be properly bound to the `Promise` object which passing `Promise.reject` by itself does not do.

Comment: You don't even need `.catch(Promise.reject);` as long as any of the `then` functions throw an error. It'll turn into a rejected promise.